# how to sort string that contains number in kotlin

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

I have a model that contains some field. I wanna sort this model before a show in recycler by sorted title. my title contains number into a string in some part like session 1 - episode 22. I use this algorithm for sort number in string type with two-digits like episode 22.

```
sortData.toObservable()
                        .sorted { o1, o2 ->
                            val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
                            val matcher = pattern.matcher(o1.title)
                            val matcher2 = pattern.matcher(o2.title)

                            if (matcher.find()) {
                                val isFind = matcher2.find()
                                val o1Num = matcher.group(0).toInt()

                                val o2Num = if (isFind) {
                                    matcher2.group(0).toInt()
                                } else {
                                    o1Num + 1
                                }

                                return@sorted o1Num - o2Num
                            } else {
                                return@sorted o1.title?.compareTo(o2.title ?: "") ?: 0
                            }
                        }
                        .toList()
                        .subscribeBy(
                                onError = {
                                    it
                                },
                                onSuccess = {
                                    sortData = it
                                }
                        )
```

my problem with this algorithm is when my title contains just simple format like episode 22 and just digits are between 0-99 it's work good but when I have a title that in this format: session 1 - episode 22 and digits are between 0-999 this algorithm won't work and I haven't any sort in my recycler. may please help me for fix this?

Comment: split your string and use only "episode 22" part to find match

Comment: dear Dharak Bhatt, this is a single string and split from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution :)

I must replace the first part with whitespace. then we can get the second part number from string and convert it to int and sort it.

```
 val matcher = pattern.matcher(o1.title?.replace("session 1", ""))
 val matcher2 = pattern.matcher(o2.title?.replace("session 1", ""))
```